# Selecting columns from numpy recarray

Tags: numpy, pandas, multidimensional-array, dataframe, recarray

I have an object from type `numpy.core.records`.recarray. I want to use it effectively as pandas dataframe. More precisely, I want to use a subset of its columns in order to obtain a new recarray, the same way you would do `pandas_dataframe[[selected_columns]]`.

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Without using pandas you can select a subset of the fields of a structured array (recarray).  For example:

```
In [338]: dt=np.dtype('i,f,i,f')
In [340]: A=np.ones((3,),dtype=dt)
In [341]: A[:]=(1,2,3,4)

In [342]: A
Out[342]: 
array([(1, 2.0, 3, 4.0), (1, 2.0, 3, 4.0), (1, 2.0, 3, 4.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f4')])
```

a subset of the fields.

```
In [343]: B=A[['f1','f3']].copy()

In [344]: B
Out[344]: 
array([(2.0, 4.0), (2.0, 4.0), (2.0, 4.0)], 
      dtype=[('f1', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4')])
```

that can be modified independently of `A`:

```
In [346]: B['f3']=[.1,.2,.3]

In [347]: B
Out[347]: 
array([(2.0, 0.10000000149011612), (2.0, 0.20000000298023224),
       (2.0, 0.30000001192092896)], 
      dtype=[('f1', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4')])

In [348]: A
Out[348]: 
array([(1, 2.0, 3, 4.0), (1, 2.0, 3, 4.0), (1, 2.0, 3, 4.0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<f4')])
```

The structured subset of fields is not highly developed.  `A[['f0','f1']]` is enough for viewing, but it will warn or give an error if you try to modify that subset.  That's why I used `copy` with `B`.

There's a set of functions that facilitate adding and removing fields from recarrays.  I'll have to look up the access pattern.  But mostly the construct a new `dtype`, and empty array, and then copy fields by name.

```
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
```

### update

With newer numpy versions, the multi-field index has changed

```
In [17]: B=A[['f1','f3']]

In [18]: B
Out[18]: 
array([(2., 4.), (2., 4.), (2., 4.)],
      dtype={'names':['f1','f3'], 'formats':['<f4','<f4'], 'offsets':[4,12], 'itemsize':16})
```

This `B` is a true `view`, referencing the same data buffer as `A`.  The `offsets` lets it ignore the missing fields.  Those fields can be removed with `repack_fields` as just documented.

But when putting this into a dataframe, it doesn't look like we need to do that.

```
In [19]: df = pd.DataFrame(A)
In [21]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   f0      3 non-null      int32  
 1   f1      3 non-null      float32
 2   f2      3 non-null      int32  
 3   f3      3 non-null      float32
dtypes: float32(2), int32(2)
memory usage: 176.0 bytes

In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame(B)
In [24]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   f1      3 non-null      float32
 1   f3      3 non-null      float32
dtypes: float32(2)
memory usage: 152.0 bytes
```

The frame created from `B` is smaller.

Sometimes when making a dataframe from an array, the array itself is used as the frame's memory.  Changing values in the source array will change the values in the frame.  But with structured arrays, pandas makes a copy of the data, with a different memory layout.

Columns of matching dtype are grouped into a common `NumericBlock`:

```
In [42]: pd.DataFrame(A)._data
Out[42]: 
BlockManager
Items: Index(['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'], dtype='object')
Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
NumericBlock: slice(1, 5, 2), 2 x 3, dtype: float32
NumericBlock: slice(0, 4, 2), 2 x 3, dtype: int32

In [43]: pd.DataFrame(B)._data
Out[43]: 
BlockManager
Items: Index(['f1', 'f3'], dtype='object')
Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
NumericBlock: slice(0, 2, 1), 2 x 3, dtype: float32
```

Comment: While this does indeed produce a copy of a recarray with a subset of fields, the copy has the same memory footprint.  In my case I'm "copying" two 200kb fields from a 9 GB recarray, and the copy also uses 9GB, even though it's only really using 400kb to store the copied objects

Comment: @Jthorpe, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-multiple-fields

Comment: Are you pointing out that accessing multiple fields returns a view? What I observed is that even `A[['f1','f3']].copy()` has the same memory footprint as A

Comment: @Jthorpe, since the time I wrote this answer the handling of multifield indexing has changed.  It's a true view.  You have to use a documented `repack` if you want a copy with reduced memory.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @hpaulj answer, you'll want to repack the copy, otherwise the copied subset will have the same size memory footprint as the original.

```py
import numpy as np
# note that you have to import this library explicitly
import numpy.lib.recfunctions

# B has a subset of "colums" but uses the same amount of memory as A
B = A[['f1','f3']].copy()

# C has a smaller memory footprint
C = np.lib.recfunctions.repack_fields(B)
```